# How to zoom and rotate webcam video which is streamed by html5 GetUserMedia API with canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-video, getusermedia

I am using **Html5 GetUserMedia** api and **canvas** for web camera streaming.while playing video i want to zoomin,zoomout,rotate etc.
in my code zoom,rotations are not working.
i coded same as **[this](http://isithackday.com/hacks/videozoomandrotate/transforming-video.html)**.but they does not use GetUserMedia API and canvas.
here is My code

<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="600"">
</canvas>
<div id="buttonWrapper">
   <input type="button" id="play" value="pause">
   <input type="button" id="plus" value="+">
   <input type="button" id="minus" value="-">
   <input type="button" id="rotateleft" value="rotate left">
   <input type="button" id="rotateright" value="rotate rightt">
</div>
  <div id="RPHTML5Video" style="position: relative; z-index: -1;">
   <video id="video" style="display: none;position:absolute;" autoplay src="">
   </video>
  </div>
   <script>
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  setInterval(function () {ctx.drawImage(video, 14, 110, 300,550);
 },20); 
 });
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', video);
 document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function(){
if(video.paused){
         video.play();
         play.innerHTML = 'pause';
       } else {
         video.pause();
         play.innerHTML = 'play';
       }

    },false);
 var zoom = 1,
 rotate = 0;
 var i,j,t;
 var properties = ['transform', 'WebkitTransform', 'MozTransform',
                'msTransform', 'OTransform'],
 prop = properties[0];
  for(i=0,j=properties.length;i<j;i++){
          if(typeof stage.style[properties[i]] !== 'undefined'){
             prop = properties[i];
 break;
 }
   }

  document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){
      zoom = zoom + 0.1;
      video.style[prop]='scale('+zoom+') rotate('+rotate+'deg)';


},false);  
document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
zoom = zoom - 0.1;
       video.style[prop]='scale('+zoom+') rotate('+rotate+'deg)';   

 },false); 
 document.getElementById("rotateleft").addEventListener("click", function(){
 rotate = rotate + 5;
       video.style[prop]='rotate('+rotate+'deg) scale('+zoom+')';   

 },false);

 document.getElementById("rotateright").addEventListener("click", function(){
 rotate = rotate - 5;
       video.style[prop]='rotate('+rotate+'deg) scale('+zoom+')';

 },false);   

 </script>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update*

The reason why this won't work is as follows: when applying CSS transform on an element it will only be rendered by browser that way. If you try to use for example the video element and draw its content to canvas the original content will be drawn excluding the CSS transformation.

[image: Quick overview]

So in order for this to work you will have to transform the canvas' context before drawing the video to it.

For example - for this to be convenient you can use this function will set all the transforms before the video is drawn:

```
function updateCanvas() {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5);
    ctx.rotate(rotate * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width * 0.5, -canvas.height * 0.5);
}
```

When you alter a transform, for example rotate, you simply do this:

```
document.getElementById("rotateright").addEventListener("click", function () {
    rotate = rotate - 5;
    updateCanvas();

}, false);
```

Now you can run the loop (here using `requestAnimationFrame`) and the video will be drawn as you intent:

```
function loop() {
    ctx.drawImage(video, 14, 110, 300, 550);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

**[I created a working demo from the posted code here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/tyFyV/)**.

Comment: video is playing,but zoom and rotation  does not working.functions for zoom and rotation seems perfect.

Comment: @NishamMahsin and my suggestions didn't change anything? I just noticed also that you have an undefined value in your code `stage` (`stage.style`);

Comment: i have changed as you suggested,but in my code too video was playing,y this   code document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){
   zoom = zoom + 0.1;
          video.style[prop]='scale('+zoom+') rotate('+rotate+'deg)';
 
 
},false);   not working

Comment: @NishamMahsin ok, I took some time-out in the thinking box and found the solution. CSS transforms doesn't follow the video element when used as source for image. Therefor you need to transform canvas instead. Please see my updated answer as well as a working fiddle.

Comment: @NishamMahsin sure, but rAF will give you proper sync to monitor refresh (setTimeout/interval are not able to do this). This is why rAF is recommended (and it works more low-level and efficient as well) :-)

Comment: while rotating the video,i want to play video completely in canvas.in your example video rectangle filled with video is rotating and rest of canvas is empty.

Comment: @NishamMahsin feel free to make any adjustment you need to meet other requirements you have. SO is not intended to produce complete solutions for users but to help solve specific problems. To fill you simply need to: either a) calculate size of clipping based on angle/zoom b) static draw image clipped/scaled to make sure it's large enough in all directions.